# How to navigate to another project in angular6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have a project (PersonalPage) inside another projects.

[image]

Normally, if I want run PersonalPage project then enter "**ng serve PersonalPage**".

I have a problem when I link two projects. I want to call (router) personal project in root project. But it does not work.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'personalpage',
        loadChildren: '../../projects/PersonalPage/src/app/app.module#AppModule',
        data: { preload: true }
    }
    , {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/personalpage',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my error when i run "**ng serve**": 
  [image]

Comment: `Module` and `App` are not the same. You can reuse `Module`, but not `App`. You can change your `App` to be used as module. But since then it stops being an application.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work that way, let me explain about the angular bootstrap process.

The entry point to every Angular application is the main.ts file which contains this last line:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

AppModule is our root module which is the entry module for our application,
if your open app.modules.ts you will find bootstrap: [AppComponent] This is the entry point component in your application.

The error you are getting above is because of ts issues, you can see a tsconfig.json file in your application which keep tracks of everything inside your project, tsconfig.app.json ("include": ["**/*.ts"])
since the module you are trying to import is outside the scope of tsconfig it is unable to find it and throwing an error to include the module inside include array to fix that issue.

Instead of creating a new app you can create a new module or library in this case.
Use nrwl.io (nrwl workspace) which makes building apps via multiple libraries very easy.

If you need to import an library inside a project you need to register it in apps tsconfig.app.json,

Still if you wish  to create two different projects, you can do it by creating a build of both the apps and serving them via express.